# Maximum K sub-arrays sum

Tags: algorithm, sum, dynamic-programming, max, arrays

I'm having trouble dealing with memoization and the bottom up approach algorithm for this problem:

suppose you have an array of elements `xi` such that `-10000 < xi < 10000` ,for all `0 < i < N`. Try to find maximum sum of T elements,T < N such that they are arranged in different sub-arrays.We don't sum the first element in each sub-array ,and we have to return the numbers K of sub-arrays as well.

An example should explain :

`T=4,
array = 3  9  1  1  7  => (3  9) and (1  7) have maximum sum 16= 9 + 7 ,K = 2`

`T=4,
array = 3  9  6  3  7  => (3 9 6 3) have maximum sum 18 = 9 + 6 + 3 , K = 1`

*T = 9, array = 14 11 18 1 1 16 12 18 0 0 11 18 9 5 14 => the contiguous sub-arrays are (14 11 18) (1 16 12 18) (11 18) K=3 and max_sum=11 + 18 + 16 + 12 + 18 + 18 = 93 ** **for T=15 array = 6 19 -29 15 9 -4 5 27 3 12 -10 5 -2 27 10 -2 11 23 -4 5 => the contiguous sub-arrays are (6 19) (-29 15 9) (5 27 3 12) (-2 27 10) (-2 11 23) with K =5 and max_sum= 19 + 15 + 9 + 27 + 3 + 12 +27 + 10 + 11 + 23=156

This is what I've done so far :

`let f[i][j][0] denotes the maximal sum for the first i   slots and using j  slots, and the i-th   slot is not used.`

`let f[i][j][1] denotes the maximal gain for the first i   slots and using j slots  , and the i-th   slot is used.`

obviously, `f[i][j][k]` can determine `f[i+1][j][k]` or `f[i+1][j+1][k]`

details:

```
    f[i+1][j+1][1]=max(f[i+1][j+1][1],f[i][j][0],f[i][j][1]+G[i+1]);
    f[i+1][j][0]=max(f[i+1][j][0],f[i][j][0],f[i][j][1]);
```

Comment: Examples are not clear: why not `T=4, array = 3 9 1 1 7 => (3 9 1 1 7) have maximum sum 18 = 9 + 1 + 1 + 7, K = 1`?

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention ,we have to peek T elements in distinct sub-arrays so that their sum is maximum,and the first element of each sub-arrays don't sum with the others.So in the example **T=4, array = 3 9 1 1 7**  we have to peek 4 elements,and the best solution is **(3 9) and (1 7) ** because 7 + 9 = 16 and first element of each sub-array ( 3 and 1) don't matter.In any other cases we had obtained a smaller sum.I hope this makes it much clear. :)

Comment: maybe "consecutive subsequence/sublist" or at least "contiguous sub-array" would be a better word? 3,9,1,7 is also a "sub array" of 3,9,1,1,7 and has sum=17, maybe add few examples as the problem is a bit hard to understand

Comment: I will add a few more examples :  **T = 9, array = 14  11  18  1  1  16  12  18  0  0  11  18  9  5  14  => the contiguous sub-arrays are (14 11 18)     (1 16 12 18)  (11 18)  K=3 and max_sum=11 + 18 + 16 + 12 + 18 + 18 = 93 **               **for T=15  array = 6  19  -29  15  9  -4  5  27  3  12  -10  5  -2  27  10  -2  11  23  -4  5 => the contiguous sub-arrays are (6 19) (-29 15 9) (5 27 3 12) (-2 27 10) (-2 11 23) with K =5 and max_sum= 19 + 15 + 9 + 27 + 3 + 12 +27 + 10 + 11 + 23=156

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version in Haskell. The function 'partitions' was written by Daniel Fischer and it partitions a list (or array) in all possible ways. The rest of the code tests the partitions with elements of length greater than one, whose combined length matches T, and returns the one with the greatest sum (summing without the first number, as requested).

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

partitions [] = [[]]
partitions (x:xs) = [[x]:p | p <- partitions xs]
                 ++ [(x:ys):yss | (ys:yss) <- partitions xs]

findMax t xs = 
  let toTest = filter (\z -> (sum $ map length z) == t) 
               $ map (\x -> filter (\y -> length y > 1) x) 
               $ partitions xs
      result = maximumBy (comparing snd) 
               (zip toTest (map (\x -> sum $ map (sum . drop 1) x) toTest))
  in putStrLn( 
       show result 
       ++ " K = " 
       ++ show (length $ fst result))


OUTPUT:
*Main> findMax 4 [3,9,1,1,7]
([[3,9],[1,7]],16) K = 2

*Main> findMax 4 [3,9,6,3,7]
([[3,9,6,3]],18) K = 1

*Main> findMax 9 [14,11,18,1,1,16,12,18,0,0,11,18,9,5,14]
([[14,11,18],[1,16,12,18],[11,18]],93) K = 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am not clear with one thing: doesn't it have a great complexity?...when length of input array is about 10000,generating all possible subsets don't take much time?I was trying to solve it using Dynamic Programming with 2 matrices and I have problem at reconstruction of solution from the matrices :)

Comment: @user2177314 Yes, great complexity. With your example of an array of length 20 and T=15, the code already takes about half a minute. A more optimal solution would definitely be appropriate for long arrays. That is quite a challenging problem. I doubt I would have a solution without studying more first. Thank you for presenting it.

Comment: I've figured it out!Thank you for you're Haskell implementation

Comment: @user2177314 that's great. will you post your answer?

Comment: yes I will post a detailed answer soon,now I'm having some problems with a homework at protocols :D